# Using Navigation Drawer in older android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Can I use **Navigation Drawer** in older android like **GingerBread**?
And If Yes , How can I use it without ActionBar as **ActionBar** is not available for Gingerbread..

Comment: Use ActionBarSherlock (Google it) for the ActionBar and the Android Support Library as suggested by Merlin in his answer. I'm using both and have a Navigation Drawer working on Froyo phones.

Comment: @Squonk Hey i did as you suggested but I am getting some errors..see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389763/navigationdrawer-with-actionbarsherlok and help if u can thnx

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) for implementing newer API features, including Navigation Drawer, into apps targeted for API level 4 or greater

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you've upgraded to the newest support library.

Here's a tutorial:  http://techbandhu.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/navigation-drawer-android/.

Answer (score 3):

There is a recent project that provide a perfect solution for it.

https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer

Answer (score 3):

Use this and your app will not crash using android Gingebread:

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1){    
         getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
         }
```

do the same if you use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`

hope that helps :)))