# NavigationDrawer with ActionBarSherlok

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, navigation-drawer

Hey I am trying to use **DrawerLayout** with **ActionBarSherlok** but i am getting error

> 06-30 15:37:18.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Priyesh/com.Priyesh.MainActivity}:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

here is my xml file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.*;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends  SherlockActivity {
DrawerLayout mydrawerlayout;
ListView drawerlist;
ArrayList<String> mplanetlist;
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawer_toggle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mydrawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
drawerlist.setAdapter(newArrayAdapter<String(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.sim        ple_list_item_2,mplanetlist));
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.show();
    actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

drawer_toggle=newActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this,mydrawerlayout,R.drawable.        ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open , R.string.drawer_close )
    {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("drawer_open");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("drawer_closse");
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mydrawerlayout.setDrawerListener(drawer_toggle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater m = getSupportMenuInflater();
    m.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

}

Comment: Use Android SDK Manager and make sure under "Tools" -> "Android SDK Tools" you have Rev. 22.0.1. On a side note `import com.actionbarsherlock.app.*;` - it's not generally a good idea to import anything using `.*` - import the individual classes you need instead.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this running on my project, which was an even more major pain because I'm using Maven.

Don't include the support library in your project, but replace the support library in the ActionBarSherlock lib folder, which is r7, with the newest r13 version. Others have said that you need to include private libraries in the order and export as well, which was not true for me because I'm using Maven.

[This tutorial was helpful in getting ABS and DrawerLayout to work together.](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it doesn't solve the issue :

- Go to Build Path > Configure Build Path > Order and Export
- Check Android and Android Dependencies libraries
- Clean and rebuild your Project

Comment: i did what u said . In order and Export Android Dependencies and private libraries is checked

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest support library installed? The class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout is only in the latest library from around a month ago (version 13).

Comment: Yes i have the latest support library(v 13) installed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. So I solved it using the following steps. It ll be useful to others.

The problem is because the compiler searching `drawer_layout` in the `activity_main.xml`.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
//You added the view file as activity_main 

mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); 
//While execution the compiler will search "drawer_layout" in the view file (activity_main.xml). But the drawer_layout is in some other xml file.
```

But there is no `"drawer_layout"` is added in the `activity_main.xml`. Its added in some other xml file

So, To solve this problem we need to add the following in the activity_main.xml.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bff">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

<!-- The content in the activity_main.xml -->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```